# RefetchQueries does not correctly update the store

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Intended outcome:

I am trying to refetch a query after a mutation. This works perfectly everywhere but I have a problem with this particular query.

```
const alertsSettingsQuery = gql`
    query alertsSettingsQuery($issuerRoleNames: [String], $receiverRoleNames: [String]) {
       alertsSettings(issuerRoleNames: $issuerRoleNames, receiverRoleNames: $receiverRoleNames) {
          ...
       }
     }
`;
```

Component querying the initial datas without variables :

```
export default compose(
    graphql(alertsSettingsQuery, {name: "alertsSettingsData"}),
    ...,
)(Administration);
```

Component refetching the datas without variables :

```
mutate({
  variables: updatedAlert,
  refetchQueries: () => [{query: alertsSettingsQuery}]
}).then((data) => {
  ...
}).catch(err => {
  ...
});
```

Actual outcome:

If I check the network tab, the datas are correctly refetched and updated but the component doesn't receive the updated datas.

If I use the apollo devtools to see what's in my cache, I have this for the original datas :

[image: initial datas]

And this from the refetch :

[image: refetch datas]

It seems like the two datas are not identified the same way.

If I change my refetchQueries to this :

```
refetchQueries: () => [{query: alertsSettingsQuery, variables: {issuerRoleNames: null, receiverRoleNames: null}}]
```

It works as expected.

I don't understand why I need to explicitly set the variables to null here, since I don't do that for any other refetch.

Version

apollo-client@2.3.4
react-apollo@<2.1.5>

Comment: I am also facing similar problem did you find solution for the above problem?